# AutoHotKey Modifier Symbol "+" For SHIFT Does Not Work

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write an [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey) script that lets me enter a comma when I hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Numpad <kbd>.</kbd>

The [modifier symbol](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is the plus sign `+`. I wrote this

```
+NumpadDot::
Send, ,
return
```

But I find this does not work. If I change the modifier to CTRL `^`, it works as I expect.

```
^NumpadDot::
Send, ,
return
```

Why does my first script not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is specific to Numpad <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>, and <kbd>9</kbd>. The reason for this is that <kbd>shift</kbd> + any of these keys results in a different button press; specifically <kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>ins</kbd>, <kbd>end</kbd>, <kbd>pg dn</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd>, and <kbd>pg up</kbd> respectively.

In your specific case, you can use `NumpadDel::`, but note that since you have to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to activate it, anything you send will be modified with <kbd>shift</kbd>. Here's a workaround:

```
NumpadDel::
Send , {shift up}{,}{shift down}
return
```

**Edit:** Correction: this appears to be the case with *all* the `Numpad` keys. Rather obviously, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, and <kbd>8</kbd> correspond to <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, and <kbd>up</kbd>. I don't know what <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad5</kbd> is supposed to do. Maybe some enlightened soul could elucidate?

Comment: Thank you so much. If I understand correctly, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Numpad <kbd>.</kbd> actually triggers 'NumpadDel'! I didn't know this.

Thanks again for your clever solution! It works!